# Using apt-get update in Dockerfile is not working

Tags: docker, apt, docker-compose, minikube

In my Mac, I'm running minikube, version
`minikube version: v1.24.0 commit: 76b94fb3c4e8ac5062daf70d60cf03ddcc0a741b`

with VirtualBox, with this command
`minikube start --vm-driver virtualbox --docker-env=[REGISTRY_PATH="myregistrypath/",BASE_VERSION=local] -p mymachine`

I'm using docker-compose to run the docker images. The relevant part of my docker-compose.yaml is

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  base:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: build/base/Dockerfile
    image: mymachine/base:${MYMACHINE_BASE_VERSION}
    command: /bin/false
```

The Dockerfile corresponding to this begins with:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
```

The python image is retrieved correctly but the apt-get update command fails.
This was working correctly some days ago. Now it's not, I haven't changed anything from my side as far as I know.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Step 3/10 : RUN apt-get -y update
 ---> Running in 5fee40f42100
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [147 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [8904 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages [27.7 kB]
Fetched 9179 kB in 2s (5714 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that problem locally. Have you tried pulling a new version of the `python:3.8-slim` image (`docker pull python:3.8-slim`)?

Comment: I changed to the 3.8 bullseye and that fixed the issue. I still have no idea what the problem is. I think It has to be a problem with my machine or configuration, because the other image is working on other machines